# Messaging between ViewControllers Using Delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to send an array from one viewController to another using protocols and delegates.  I declared the delegate on viewcontroller B and used the following code in viewcontroller A to send the message from A to B.  The protocol's method is didReceiveMessage.  Unfortunately, the message never arrives.

Attached is the code from viewController A

```
- (IBAction) graphPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

 GraphingViewController *gvc=[[GraphingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:gvc animated:YES];
 [gvc release];

 [delegate didReceiveMessage:brain.internalExpression];

}
```

and the code from viewcontrollerB

```
- (IBAction) ViewdidLoad {
 CalculatorViewController *cvc =[[CalculatorViewController alloc] init];
 cvc.delegate=self;
 [cvc release];  
}

- (void) didReceiveMessage:(NSMutableArray *)expression {

 NSLog(@"message received from CalculatorAppDelegate");
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you doing in second sample? You created an object, assign its delegate property and then released it. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If that is code from your application it could probably be from releasing cvc at the end of your ViewDidLoad method.

init would give it a retain count of 1, and the release would take it back to 0.

Also the code seems sort of backwards, if you wanted to set view A as the delegate for view B, you would do so in view A.

Unless there is a more complex reason to use a delegate that I'm not seeing from the code, I would just keep a pointer around to the child if you really need to send it messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Any suggestions on how to keep the pointer to the child around.  If I subclass view A from the child, I'll lose the information I need.

Comment: Just create an instance variable on the parent controller and assign the child view to it. Make sure to retain it when you assign it and release when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have posted, you are just getting rid of the Calculator VC after creating it. I would recommend adding an `@property` to the second VC and using it to store a pointer to the Calculator. It should be a `retain` property. Then set the delegate of that property to self.

Also, you make sure to use an `assign` property for the delegate value, and try to use the property syntax (`self.delegate`) whenever possible.

There could absolutely be more going on here, so if this doesn't actually solve the problem try and post up more of your code (header files, what connections are made in IB, etc.)

Edit:  For the record, the method is `-(void)viewDidLoad`, not `-(void)ViewDidLoad`, so that could be contributing to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are trying to pass an array from one view controller to another.Well i use in this way.Here is the code

```
- (IBAction) graphPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

 GraphingViewController *gvc=[[GraphingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 gvc.myArray=infoArray;
 [self presentModalViewController:gvc animated:YES];
 [gvc release];
}
```

Where `myArray` is array in your GraphingViewController,You just need to make property of this array with retain attribute,simply as

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

And you need to Synthesize it as well.